# action bar showing large space between app icon and menu items

Tags: android, android-actionbar, menuitem

My action bar shows the app icon on the left, then has a large space, and then shows some of my menu items on the right (the rest go into overflow).  The problem is that the "large space" is big enough to hold several more icons.  Why isn't it being used?

My menu resource looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item
    android:id="@+id/menu_a"
    android:icon="@drawable/a"
    android:title="a"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom" >

    <menu>
      <item ... />
      ...
    </menu>
  </item>
  ...
  <item
    android:id="@+id/menu_n"
    android:icon="@drawable/n"
    android:title="n"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom" >
    ...
  </item>
</menu>
```

In my Activity, I have:

```
  @Override
  public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView (R.layout.main_activity);

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar(); 
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false); 
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled (true);
    ...
  }
```

and

```
  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu)
  {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.nav_menu, menu);
    return true;
  }
```

I have a suspicion it has something to do with the app title (setDispalyShowTitleEnabled), which I have disabled.  Maybe I'm doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong with your code.

AtionBar by default allows only 2-3 menu items even when there is enough room to accommodate 4-5.

May be to maintain better UI.

So, instead of

```
android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
```

use

```
android:showAsAction="always"
```

to have the MenuItems always present on the ActionBar instead of going into the overflow menu.

Comment: Then, how do you make it work on various sized screens?  I'm hoping to avoid writing code which computes how many icons will fit.

Comment: Thats what, to support all screen sizes, we must use **ifRoom**.But 3 menu items shouldn't be a problem on any screen. Moreover, how important these menu items are, user doesn't want his actionbar filled with them. You better say how many menu items you have and how many must be always shown.

Comment: So, are you saying that the limit of showing 2 icons (on my kyocera) is by design rather than showing as many as the developer asks for?  Are you sure?

Comment: Yeah. But **rather than showing as many as the developer asks for**, you can ask using **android:showAsAction="always"**

Comment: Ok, thanks for confirming.  And, yes, I'm familiar with "always" - just trying to avoid it.